# Error: method __toString() must not throw an exception symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, tostring

I am working with Symfony2 and I faced with an error:

> Error: Method Proxies__CG__\Sprint\SiteBundle\Entity\Task::__toString() must not throw an exception

Here is this this code in my `Entity\Task.php`:

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->title;
}
```

The main problem, that on my local version of this site everything okay and I have this error only on my live site. But they are similar!

Here my Entity\Task.php code:

```
class Task
    {

    use TraitDateTimeFields;

    use TraitCreatorTimeFields;

    use TraitTaskTeamFields;

    use TraitTimeTrackFields;

    use TraitTagFields;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sprint\SiteBundle\Entity\Tag")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *  name="s_task_tags",
     *  joinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="task_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  },
     *  inverseJoinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  }
     *  )
     */
    private $tags;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @Gedmo\TreePathSource
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="depth", nullable=true)
     * @Gedmo\TreeLevel
     * @var integer
     */
    private $depth;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="path", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Gedmo\TreePath
     * @var string
     */
    private $path;

    /** Это группа
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", name="flag_group")
     * @var string
     */
    private $flagGroup = false;

    /** Архив
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", name="flag_archive")
     * @var string
     */
    private $flagArchive = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="number", nullable=false)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $number = '';

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="title", nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="resource")
     * @var string
     * @deprecated
     */
    protected $resource = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="bonus")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $bonus = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="state")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $state = TaskState::C_WORKING;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="ttype")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $type = TaskType::C_INNER;

    /** Начало
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="start_to", nullable=true)
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $startTo;

    /** Дедлайн
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="deadline_to", nullable=true)
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $deadlineTo;

    /** Срочно
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", name="flag_quicly")
     * @var string
     */
    private $flagQuickly = false;

    /** Формирование бюджета
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", name="flag_budget")
     * @var string
     */
    private $flagBudget = true;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Sprint\SiteBundle\Entity\EstimateOperatingRow", mappedBy="task", cascade={"detach","persist"}, orphanRemoval=false)
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    protected $estimateRows;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sprint\SiteBundle\Entity\Project", inversedBy="tasks")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @var \Sprint\SiteBundle\Entity\Project
     */
    protected $project;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sprint\SiteBundle\Entity\Task", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @Gedmo\TreeParent
     * @var \Sprint\SiteBundle\Entity\Task
     */
    protected $parent;

    /**  Подзадачи
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Sprint\SiteBundle\Entity\Task", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    public $children;

    /**  Задания
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Sprint\SiteBundle\Entity\TaskAssignment", mappedBy="task", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    public $assignment;

    /**  Активность
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Sprint\SiteBundle\Entity\TaskActivityItem", mappedBy="task", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    public $activity;

    private $activitySummary = [];

    protected $operationItems = [];

    /**
     * Task constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children      = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->activity      = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->auditors      = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->staff         = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->tags          = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->estimateRows  = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->assignment    = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function getTreeTitle()
    {
        return str_pad('', ($this->depth-1)*6*4, '&nbsp;', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ($this->flagGroup ? '&#xf115; ' : '&#xf044; ') . $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPaySummary()
    {
        $result = [
            'total'   => 0,
            'paid'    => 0,
            'remains' => 0,
            'credit'  => 0
        ];

        $now = new \DateTime();

        foreach ($this->getOperationItems() as $opt) {
            $optSummary = $opt->getSummary();

            $result['total']   += $optSummary['total'];
            $result['paid']    += $optSummary['paid'];
            $result['remains'] += $optSummary['remains'];

            if ($opt->getExpectedAt()) {
                $df = $now->diff($opt->getExpectedAt());

                if ($df->invert) {
                    $result['credit'] += $optSummary['remains'];
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getActivitySummary($hourPrice, $forced = false)
    {
        if ($forced) {
            $this->activitySummary = [];
        }
        if ($this->activitySummary) {
            return $this->activitySummary;
        }
        $result = [
            'plannedHours' => 0,
            'plannedSmens' => 0,
            'plannedPrice' => 0,

            'plannedHoursRemains' => 0,
            'plannedSmensRemains' => 0,
            'plannedPriceRemains' => 0,

            'developHours' => 0,
            'developSmens' => 0,
            'developPrice' => 0,

            'developHoursRemains' => 0,
            'developSmensRemains' => 0,
            'developPriceRemains' => 0,

            'innerHours' => 0,
            'innerSmens' => 0,
            'innerPrice' => 0,

            'innerHoursRemains' => 0,
            'innerSmensRemains' => 0,
            'innerPriceRemains' => 0,

            'outherHours' => 0,
            'outherSmens' => 0,
            'outherPrice' => 0,

            'outherHoursRemains' => 0,
            'outherSmensRemains' => 0,
            'outherPriceRemains' => 0,

            'resource'     => 0
        ];


        if ($this->flagGroup) {
            $childs = $this->getChildren();

            if (!$childs->isEmpty()) {
                $cnt         = $childs->count();
                $planSummary = 0.0;

                foreach ($childs as $c) {
                    $planSummary += $c->getPlannedHours();
                    $cRes = $c->getActivitySummary($hourPrice, $forced);

                    foreach ($cRes as $k => $v) {
                        $result[$k] += $v;
                    }
                }

                $this->setPlannedHours($planSummary);
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($this->activity as $a) {
                switch ($a->getActivity()) {
                    case TaskActivity::C_DEVELOP :
                        $result['plannedHours'] += $a->getSpend();
                        $result['developHours'] += $a->getSpend();
                        break;
                    case TaskActivity::C_INNER :
                        $result['plannedHours'] += $a->getSpend();
                        $result['innerHours'] += $a->getSpend();
                        break;
                    case TaskActivity::C_OUTHER :
                        $result['plannedHours'] += $a->getSpend();
                        $result['outherHours'] += $a->getSpend();
                        break;
                }
            }

            $result['plannedHoursRemains'] = $this->getPlannedHours() - $result['plannedHours'];
            $result['developHoursRemains'] = $this->getDevelopHours() - $result['developHours'];
            $result['innerHoursRemains']   = $this->getInnerHours() - $result['innerHours'];
            $result['outherHoursRemains']  = $this->getOutherHours() - $result['outherHours'];
        }

        $result['plannedSmens'] = $result['plannedHours'] / 8;
        $result['developSmens'] = $result['developHours'] / 8;
        $result['innerSmens']   = $result['innerHours']   / 8;
        $result['outherSmens']  = $result['outherHours']  / 8;

        $result['plannedPrice'] = $result['plannedHours'] * $hourPrice;
        $result['developPrice'] = $result['developHours'] * $hourPrice;
        $result['innerPrice']   = $result['innerHours']   * $hourPrice;
        $result['outherPrice']  = $result['outherHours']  * $hourPrice;

        $result['plannedSmensRemains'] = $result['plannedHoursRemains'] / 8;
        $result['developSmensRemains'] = $result['developHoursRemains'] / 8;
        $result['innerSmensRemains']   = $result['innerHoursRemains']   / 8;
        $result['outherSmensRemains']  = $result['outherHoursRemains']  / 8;

        $result['plannedPriceRemains'] = $result['plannedHoursRemains'] * $hourPrice;
        $result['developPriceRemains'] = $result['developHoursRemains'] * $hourPrice;
        $result['innerPriceRemains']   = $result['innerHoursRemains']   * $hourPrice;
        $result['outherPriceRemains']  = $result['outherHoursRemains']  * $hourPrice;


        if ($this->plannedHours) {
            $result['resource'] = round(
                ($result['developHours'] + $result['innerHours'] + $result['outherHours']) / $this->plannedHours * 100
            );
        }

        $this->activitySummary = $result;
        return $this->activitySummary;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getResource()
    {
        return $this->resource;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $title
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool|\DateInterval
     */
    public function getTimeToDeadline()
    {
        return $this->deadlineTo ? $this->deadlineTo->diff(new \DateTime()) : null;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFlagQuickly()
    {
        $interval = $this->getTimeToDeadline();
        return ($interval && $interval->invert && $interval->days*24 < 8);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $flagQuickly
     */
    public function setFlagQuickly($flagQuickly)
    {
        $this->flagQuickly = $flagQuickly;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFlagBudget()
    {
        return $this->flagBudget;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $flagBudget
     */
    public function setFlagBudget($flagBudget)
    {
        $this->flagBudget = $flagBudget;
    }

    /**
     * @param Project $project
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setProject($project)
    {
        $this->project = $project;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Project
     */
    public function getProject()
    {
        return $this->project;
    }

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|static
     */
    public function getDisplayedChildren()
    {
        $criteria = Criteria::create();
        $criteria->orderBy(['createdAt' => 'DESC']);
        $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('parent', $this));
        return $this->children->matching($criteria);
    }

    /**
     * @param Task $parent
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setParent($parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Task
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $startTo
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setStartTo($startTo)
    {
        $this->startTo = $startTo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getStartTo()
    {
        return $this->startTo;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $deadlineTo
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setDeadlineTo($deadlineTo)
    {
        $this->deadlineTo = $deadlineTo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDeadlineTo()
    {
        return $this->deadlineTo;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $number
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setNumber($number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNumber()
    {
        return $this->number;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $resource
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setResource($resource)
    {
        $this->resource = $resource;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEstimateRows()
    {
        return $this->estimateRows;
    }

    /**
     * @param $estimateRow
     */
    public function addEstimateRow($estimateRow)
    {
        $estimateRow->setTask($this);
        $this->estimateRows->add($estimateRow);
    }

    /**
     * @param $estimateRow
     */
    public function removeEstimateRow($estimateRow)
    {
        $estimateRow->setTask(null);
        $this->estimateRows->removeElement($estimateRow);
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $estimateRows
     */
    /*
    public function setEstimateRows($estimateRows)
    {
        $this->estimateRows = $estimateRows;
    }
    */

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getState()
    {
        return $this->state;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $state
     */
    public function setState($state)
    {
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $type
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $tags
     */
    public function setTags($tags)
    {
        $this->tags = $tags;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBonus()
    {
        return $this->bonus;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $bonus
     */
    public function setBonus($bonus)
    {
        $this->bonus = $bonus;
    }

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getActivity()
    {
        return $this->activity;
    }

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getAssignment()
    {
        return $this->assignment;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|static
     */
    public function getDisplayedActivity()
    {
        $criteria = Criteria::create();
        $criteria->orderBy(['createdAt' => 'DESC']);
        $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->isNull('parent'));
        return $this->activity->matching($criteria);
    }

    /**
     * @param $activity
     */
    public function addActivity($activity)
    {
        $this->activity->add($activity);
    }

    /**
     * @param $activity
     */
    public function removeActivity($activity)
    {
        $this->activity->removeElement($activity);
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDepth()
    {
        return $this->depth;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $depth
     */
    public function setDepth($depth)
    {
        $this->depth = $depth;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $path
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFlagGroup()
    {
        return $this->flagGroup;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $flagGroup
     */
    public function setFlagGroup($flagGroup)
    {
        $this->flagGroup = $flagGroup;
    }

    public function getDirector()
    {
        return $this->project ? $this->project->getDirector() : $this->director;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFlagArchive()
    {
        return $this->flagArchive;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $flagArchive
     */
    public function setFlagArchive($flagArchive)
    {
        $this->flagArchive = $flagArchive;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getOperationItems()
    {
        return $this->operationItems;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $operations
     */
    public function setOperationItems($operations)
    {
        $this->operationItems = $operations;
    }
}
```

Comment: give full code of the Entity and backtrace

Comment: it is seems what you have error in the code, which generates an Exception. Do you declare $this->title property?

Comment: @mochalygin yes I do

Comment: May be because of nullable? Try to cast to string: return (string)$this->title;

Comment: "*But they are similar*" ???

Comment: did you happen to find out in the end what was causing this? I.e. just found couple of similar errors from our prod logs with similarly basic entity setup.

Answer (score 0):

You declared $title prop as "nullable". That means, what it can be NULL.
But `__toString()` must always return the string value. 
Try to cast to string return value.

```
public function __toString() 
{ 
   return (string)$this->title; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the function 1. is not called explicitly statically because then `$this` does not exist and 2. `$this->title` actually has a value or is casted to string because otherwise it would return `null`.

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return (isset($this) && $this->title !== '')
        ? (string)$this->title
        : '';
}
```

Comment: `$this->title !== ''` is redundant